# Angular 6 call localhost API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular6, angular-httpclient

I am trying to call an API locally in my angular 6 app, the API URL is `http://localhost/myapi` I added a proxy config file that point to this URL but I got
`404` error when I run my app.

My proxy.config.json file:

```
{
  "/api/*":{
    "target":"http://localhost/myapi",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

package.json file:

```
"serve-dev": "ng serve --source-map=false --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

http.service.ts file:

```
export class HttpService{
     static serverApiUrl : string  = "/api/"
}
```

auth.service.ts file :

```
 this.http.get(HttpService.serverApiUrl+"site/check-auth")
            .map(response => {
                if(response['auth'] == 1) {
          return true;
                } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/auth'])
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

In the console I got this:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/site/check-auth
```

any suggestions.

Comment: Are you doing `ng serve` or `npm start`?

Comment: npm run serve-dev

Comment: the app builds but the request return 404 error

Comment: the real api url is localhost/myapi/site/check-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to [rewrite the URL path](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy#rewriting-the-url-path), using something like this:

```json
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": "/myapi"
        }
    }
}
```

I've removed `/*` from the prefix you had and added a `pathRewrite` section. I believe what you had before was attempting to proxy to `localhost/myapi/api/site/check-auth` (with that extra `/api`), which should be stripped with the `pathRewrite` section.