# Angular8: Call localhost Rest Api services

Tags: django, angular, proxy, http-error, bad-request

I developed my web application with Angular 8. The backend is a rest api that I developed with django rest framework and it's viewed just in the localhost. I tested it and it works fine. For example the service `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/devices` gives a list of devices. It gives a good results if I test it with browser or curl command. 
I'm calling this service from my angular app. I executed the angular app with the command: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201`

If I open the web application in the browser with `http://127.0.0.1:4201/api/devices` the service `/api/devices` is well called and I get the list of devices in my web page. but if I open the web application with my LAN IP address like that `http://192.168.1.59:4201/api/devices`, so I get `HTTP 400 bad request` error in my console.

[image]
And the same error is shown in django server traces:  `GET /api/devices/ HTTP/1.1" 400 26`

After some searches in the internet I concluded that this error is frequently coming from angular app especially the proxy:
my proxy config file proxy.config.json is:

```
{
    "/api" : {
        "target": "http://localhost:8000",
        "secure": false
  }
}
```

I mad other searches and I found an answer to similar question [Angular 6 call localhost API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512301/angular-6-call-localhost-api) and after following the angular doc https://angular.io/guide/build in "Proxying to a backend server" section then I modified my proxy config file to:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Has any one an idea what can be the main cause of the issue? and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
   ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --disable-host-check
```